# pandas groupby on year, month for means gives blank values for year month

Tags: pandas

I am doing the aggregation right, but I need to have the years and months filled in the columns. Currently it looks like:

```
YEAR    MONTH   WEEK    a   b   
2017    1         1    .5   6
                  2    .3   8
                  3    .9   10
```

I want:

```
YEAR    MONTH   WEEK        a   b   
    2017    1         1    .5   6
    2017    1         2    .3   8
    2017    1         3    .9   10
```

My current code:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(["YEAR", "MONTH", "WEEK"])["a", "b"].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is there, it just isn't displayed by default when you `print` a Pandas DataFrame.  To change this default:

```
pd.options.display.multi_sparse = False
```

Then print again, and you'll get the output you want.

Comment: thanks that worked! but when i write to excel it doesn't show up in the excel file...

Comment: OK, well this question didn't mention Excel so perhaps the best thing would be to post a new question about Excel.  I'd be happy to look at it if you comment with a link here and include your reproducing code and example input/output in the new question.